# Vectorize a code that finds the roots of polynomials stored in matrices

Tags: matlab, structure

I need some tips on how to vectorize a code that finds the roots of polynomials stored in matrices. What I have is a multidimensional array that contains *100* matrices of *100-by-3* size. I'm pasting the code below

```
one = ones ( 100, 100 );

poly.struc = reshape( [ one; gr_fac1; - gr_fac2 ], 100, 3, [] ); 

poly_roots_select = zeros ( 100, 100);

for j = 1:1:100

  poly_matrices = poly.struc ( :, :, j );

    for i = 1:1:100

      poly_select = poly_matrices ( i, : );

      poly_roots = roots ( poly_select );

      poly_roots_select ( i , j)  =  poly_roots ( real ( poly_roots) > 0 , 1 ) ; 

    end

end
```

I would like to remove both *for* loops. At minimum I like to be able to access the matrices stored in *poly.struc* array without putting a loop for this. Is there also any other way to be able to pass row vectors from a matrix to *roots* function without needing a loop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can assign a matrix `B=[one;gr_fact;gr_fact2]` .... *(just makes it a little more neat)*

Then make sure that `M x N x P = numel(B)` .... *where M,N,P are dimensions of your new 3D array and M,N,P = 100,3,100*

you should modify reshape statement to this:

```
poly.struc = reshape(B,100,3,100);
```

Access each matrix using `poly.struc(:,:,i)`

You cannot avoid loops if you have to access multiple rows/columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I had made the question more specific. I had used _reshape_ function before. Please have a look at it now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! So you think that in this program, it's not possible to remove _for_ loops? I was thinking to get rid of at least one _for_ loop by passing this _poly.struc_ as an argument to a function  which also accept index _j_ as other argument. Before I make a call to the function, I can vectorize _j_ and hopefully function would take the vector _j_ as an argument. Inside this function, I can use one _for_ loop to calculate the roots. What do you think?

Comment: You can pass specific index co-ordinates as a function argument and access a particular element or a vector or a matrix..

but if you want to do that iteratively i.e. for all elements/vectors/matrices, then you need loop.

you need not vectorize to calculate polynomial roots... Are you doing a polynomial regression?? 

well in any case you need a matrix inversion or maybe linear optimization (which takes input as a matrix). But your system seems to be overdetermined and I assume that you are just optimizing. Is it so ?

Comment: No I'm not doing polynomial regression. I'm just finding the roots of the 2nd order polynomials (whose coefficients depends on two parameters _i_ and _j_) and plot them. I tried quite hard to code it in way that at east I don't have nested _for_ loops. If the _roots_ function of Matlab was taking matrices as input instead of vectors, then I could have removed one loop, or maybe vectorize it totally.

Comment: you can also use fsolve to solve a function (it is based on levenberg marquardt optimization) 

you can even solve the polynomial using Gauss-seidel method..